# Find data in Excel that meets criteria, find min date, return a third value

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, min

[image]

I have 4 columns in Excel.

I want to pull out any jobs which have fallen behind and show the customer name.

Column A = Customer name

Column B = Provisional service date for them

Column C = Final Status of Service ("completed", "book in now!", "book in later")

Column D = Customer whose Annual Service is most urgent

I am only interested in the "Book in now!" entries in column C. Then I need to cross reference this with Column B to find the earliest date.  When it's found the earliest date I need it to check the customer name in Column A and return the Customer Name in Column D

Comment: Questions of this type are greatly aided by a small supply of CSV data, and more importantly still, an attempt of your own. You may wish to expand on the meaning of the colloquialism "put out any jobs" - do you mean they should be written to a different worksheet? Should they set a column flag so they can be found using an auto filter? etc.

Comment: Thanks halfer- I was having difficulties loading a csv data image to help explain (and I had tried myself for some time beforehand without success). Thankfully Sadjad was able to give me a perfect solution - despite my somewhat poor explanation. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: Ah great Eleanor, pleased you fixed it. Do consider [accepting Sadjad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it led you to your solution. Although this one seems to have worked out fine, it's worth noting that questions containing a non-working attempt are generally better received by readers.

Comment: Hi halfer - I noticed after I posted that it didn't pull through the oldest date - I'm trying to load up an image but it tells me I don't have authority to do that yet - in order to make it easier to show. He's got me more than half way there! :-)

Comment: OK. I would recommend rolling back your edit and either adding it as an addendum (if it is genuinely a small thing related to the original question) or ask a new question. My guess would be that your new question state invalidates the work that Sadjad has put in, which is not fair to him. I am not an Excel user though, so I cannot make that judgement. Perhaps you could comment under Sadjad's answer to see if he can make an adjustment?

Comment: Ahh I see your point. Sorry Sadjad - not sure what I originally said now as very new to all this - and overtyped it all. I'm sure you answered what I originally asked - and possibly I've just misused the Index and Match so that it's not picking up the earliest date?

Comment: You have a [revision history here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49838500/revisions), and in there you can roll back to earlier versions if that is appropriate.

Comment: Since you created the extra column (E) containing dates of services of the status "book in now!" (which are two in your case in the image), you can try the following in the last column 
`=(INDEX(B24:B28;MATCH(MIN(E24:E28);C24:C28;0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a fifth column (**E**). In that column write a formula  that returns the date of the those who have "Book in now!" (`=if(C2="Book in now!", B2, "")`). Now all you should do is to find the minimum in column E and since `vlookup` doesn't work backwards, use combination of `Index` and `Match` functions to find the name (see: [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/503530-vlookup-reverse-direction.html)). Note that in my solution you only get 1 name and not all urgent customers.

Comment: Thank you so much Sadjad - I've now got it working - perfect! :-)

Comment: Sorry Sadjad - it needs a tweak still as it's pulling through a company but not the one with the earliest date. If you can think of how I can do this it would be much appreciated! I've now managed to add an image.

Comment: @EleanorDangerfield Sorry, my bad! the formula returns the first place that meets the condition. So, if you want the earliest, then you can simply sort the list based on date. I sort is not convenient, then we should try to find another solution

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a long formula, but I believe it's required for this complexity:

```
=INDEX(B24:B28,MIN(IF((D24:D28=D30)*(C24:C28=MIN(IF(D24:D28=D30,C24:C28))),ROW(B24:B28)-ROW()+1,9^99)))
```

This formula is to be entered as an array formula, i.e. after entering the formula, do not press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

The innermost IF is basically finding the earliest date(s) that related to column D being 'book in now!!', then the outermost IF finds the rows for which both the date match the previously found earliest date(s) and for which column D has the value 'book in now!!'. If the earliest date is not calculated first, then it would find the earliest date regardless of what is in column D, which will not necessarily be the ealiest 'book in now!!' date.

---

If you can use column E, then the inner IF can be removed to something like this:

```
=INDEX(B24:B28,MIN(IF((D24:D28=D30)*(C24:C28=MIN(E24:E28)),ROW(B24:B28)-ROW()+1,9^99)))
```

(But it's still an array formula)

[image]